# Does the property decorator function execute only when it is called?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to know if the requiresQuery will only execute when it's called or anytime you make a query regarding that table.

```
class SomeTable(Base):
    ...
    someJson = Column(Text)
    ...
    @property
    def requiresQuery(self):
        filterValue = getValueFromJson(self.someJson)
        someQuery = session.query(OtherTable).filter(OtherTable.filter == filterValue)
        return getValue(someQuery)
```

Now using that table:

```
# Query SomeTable and never ask for the value
session.query(SomeTable).one().someJson
# Does the requiresQuery execute here?
# Or does it need to be called explicitly
session.query(SomeTable).one().requiresQuery
# requiresQuery has been called here.
```

Comment: `@decorator def func():..` is exactly equivalent to `def func():... func = decorator(func)`.

Comment: Why not test it?